# Build iohook from source (with electron 4.0.0 and vue)

Tags: vue.js, electron

I used [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to create a vue app and then i added [electron(4.0.0)](https://github.com/electron/electron) via a plugin called [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder). Everything is ok and works properly.

The problem is with [iohook](https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook) which, as stated on their [documentation](https://wilix-team.github.io/iohook/), has prebuild versions for electron ABI <= 57 (in reality it's <= 64). It seems that on my project it automatically downloads and uses `electron ABI(64)` which is `electron(3.0.0)` (verified with [node-abi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-abi)).

`electron(4.0.3/4)` is `ABI(69)` (which is not supported). Judging by these circumstances i'm also considering that `electron 4.0.0` has `ABI(69)` as well

`iohook` needs things specified in `package.json` [arch type, etc..] which i did specify.

`iohook` also wants me to `npm run build` but as of now it doesn't generate any build folder what so ever.

My solutions are:

**Go back to electron 3.0.0**

1. What are the differences between `electron 3.0.0` and `electron 4.0.x`

**Manually build iohook from source**

2. Their documentation on manual building seems poor, at least for me. How do i actually do that? It's always throwing me errors / saying to cd in the lib's directory and `npm run compile` which doesn't work because `arch type doesn't match`.

As of now i want to manually build `iohook`.

**UPDATE**
I tried with `electron 3.0.0` (barebones) and it's still throwing:

`Error: Cannot find module 'F:\DOCS\OneDrive\Programming\NODE\type_analysis\dist_electron\builds\electron-v64-win32-x64\build\Release\iohook.node'
    at webpackEmptyContext (webpack:///./node_modules/iohook_sync?:2:10)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/iohook/index.js?:10:80)
    at Object../node_modules/iohook/index.js (F:\DOCS\OneDrive\Programming\NODE\type_analysis\dist_electron\index.js:252:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (F:\DOCS\OneDrive\Programming\NODE\type_analysis\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/background.js?:15:16)
    at Module../src/background.js (F:\DOCS\OneDrive\Programming\NODE\type_analysis\dist_electron\index.js:1395:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (F:\DOCS\OneDrive\Programming\NODE\type_analysis\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./src/background.js?:1:18)
    at Object.0 (F:\DOCS\OneDrive\Programming\NODE\type_analysis\dist_electron\index.js:1406:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (F:\DOCS\OneDrive\Programming\NODE\type_analysis\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)`

**UPDATE 2**
Doesn't work with `electron 2.0.0` either...
I also added the `cmake-js` thing in package.json

`"cmake-js": {
  "runtime": "electron",
  "runtimeVersion": "2.0.0"
}`

Tried `electron-rebuild -f -w iohook` as well, didn't solve the problem either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for Electron v2+ is here now (try iohook version 0.4+). We are currently working on the Win32/64 support for electron 4. All other platforms are fine. You can follow the debug here : https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/pull/157